# Django CSRF on 500 error page with a form

Tags: django, forms, csrf

I got a 500 error page which has a form, however the CSRF token is not generated when 500 error page is thrown. What's the best way to generate the CSRF token on a 500 error page to make the form post work? Should I just define my own custom 500 error view?

Comment: What's generating the error? Django? You? Your server?

Comment: let's say Django throws the error and renders the 500.html

Comment: If that's the case and the page is supposed to throw a 500 server error by design you will need to find what's generating the error, catch it, and work it accordingly.

Comment: What about defining a view and csrf-protect it?  That didn't work?

Comment: @Chris yes I am trying to define a custom view but I am struggling to find the place to put handler500 = 'mysite.views.my_custom_error_view', the django site say put it in URLConf but where exactly?

Comment: I have put handler500 = 'mysite.views.my_custom_error_view' into the urls.py but it's not reaching the custom view

Comment: OK, just figured out I need to put the handler500 into the main urls.py, not the app specific one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I tried defining the custom 500 view and worked, for anyone who has the same issue, here it's how:

define a custom 500 error view

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def server_error(request):
    vars = {}
    return render(request, '500.html', vars, status=500)
```

then in the main urls.py add:

```
handler500 = 'your_app.views.errors.server_error'
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the response gets sent with HTTP status code 200 (success), when there is a real problem.  This just bit me when an AJAX call considered the response a success when it actually failed.  Add a status=500 to your render call.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the token on the ajax request

```
                          var data = {
                            errorresponse: errorresponse,
                            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}',
                            }
                                 
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "/your-target-url/",  
                                data: data,  // this passes data context into view
                                success: function(data) {
```